# Rare context in which 'one of the' is used

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I understand the logic behind use of plural verb in 'one of the' sentences like

"He's one of the soldiers who have been shot" OR "this is one of the buildings that have been burnt down"

But it's extremely confusing whether to use singular or plural verb when it comes to sentences that don't start with a "S/he is one of the + who" or "this is one of the+ who/that".
Example:

"One of the soldiers who HAVE been shot"  OR "One of the soldiers who HAS been shot" which is correct?

Comment: However the sentence starts, 'the solders who have been shot' is plural, thus you write 'who **have** been shot'. One of the solders who have been shot is my cousin.

Comment: However, 'one of the soldiers has been shot' is possible..

Comment: This is not rare.

Comment: Either plural or singular can be used according to its suitability. This is a case I too had had trouble with as an English learner. Good job bringing it up.

Answer (score 2):

Either **has** or **have** could be correct depending on what you are trying to say.

The meaning can often be clarified by punctuation:

> One of the soldiers who have been shot is being treated by the Medic."

This means some of the soldiers have been shot, and the Medic is treating one of them.

> One of the soldiers, who has been shot, is being treated by the Medic.

This means just one of the soldiers has been shot, and he is being treated.

The difference can also be heard in speech (when you can't see commas) by the pauses between words, and the intonation of the speaker.